# Why is Doxygen not picking up code comments

Tags: doxygen

I have created a doxygen configuration file with the following settings (the ones I believe are pertinent to my question)

```
    JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF=YES
    OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_JAVA=YES
    EXTRACT_ALL=YES
    EXTRACT_PRIVATE=YES
    EXTRACT_STATIC=YES
    EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS=YES
```

I am documenting a javascript project. I just want it to pick up my JAVASDOC style comments in the source files. But it isn't working.

Here is an example of a file

```
    /// \file
    
    export default class FieldController {
    
        constructor(){
    
        }
    
            /// \brief  A function
            /// \param  A param
            /// \param  Another param
            /// \return Some return value
            method1(){
    
            }
        }
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen? what is the name of the file?

Comment: 1.8.13. fieldcontroller.js. I should mention that it is creating an entry for the file, just not picking up the comments.

Comment: Note that 1.8.13 is already a bit older (December 29, 2016), the current version is 1.8.20.

Comment: Note that the setting name `OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_JAVA` is incorrect this should be `OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA`

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Hopefully this can be helpful to others in the same problem. It's working great now and parsing Javascript files with ease. Works with ES6, right out of the box.

Add the following setting:

```
    EXTENSION_MAPPING = js=JavaScript
```

> If you have a larger project consisting of a source directory or tree you should assign the root directory or directories to the INPUT tag, and add one or more  file patterns to the FILE_PATTERNS tag (for instance *.cpp *.h). Only files that match one of the patterns will be parsed

> Doxygen selects the parser to use depending on the extension of the
> files it parses. With this tag you can assign which parser to use for
> a given extension. Doxygen has a built-in mapping, but you can
> override or extend it using this tag. The format is ext=language,
> where ext is a file extension, and language is one of the parsers
> supported by doxygen: IDL, Java, JavaScript, Csharp (C#), C, C++, D,
> PHP, md (Markdown), Objective-C, Python, Slice, VHDL, Fortran (fixed
> format Fortran: FortranFixed, free formatted Fortran: FortranFree,
> unknown formatted Fortran: Fortran. In the later case the parser tries
> to guess whether the code is fixed or free formatted code, this is the
> default for Fortran type files).
>
> For instance to make doxygen treat .inc files as Fortran files
> (default is PHP), and .f files as C (default is Fortran), use:
> inc=Fortran f=C.